# How to create a legend from geojson data with react-leaflet

Tags: legend, geojson, react-leaflet

I've got some data represented in my map and I want to create a legend that has the same image of my data and name.
My data are Geojson files.

My map looks like this :

**Map without Legend**

[image: Map without Legend]

I want to develop a legend like this :

**Map with Legend**

[image: Map with Legend]

This is my code that represents data to the Map :

```
import React from "react";
import L from "leaflet";
import {
   MapContainer,
   TileLayer,
   GeoJSON,
   Marker,
   Popup,
   LayersControl,
} from "react-leaflet";

import noeud from "./../data/Noeud.json";
import section from "./../data/section.json";
import casier from "./../data/casier.json";

function Macarte() {

  const noeud_icon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: noeud_image,
  iconSize: [10, 10],
 });

 function casier_style() {
    return {
      fillColor: "transparent",
      color: "red",
   };
  }

 function section_style() {
   return {
      color: "black",
   };
 }

 return (
    <MapContainer className="map" center={[45.7133, 5.52826]} zoom={11}>
    <LayersControl position="topright" />
    <TileLayer
     attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
     url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />

   {noeud.features.map((data_noeud) => (
    <Marker
      icon={noeud_icon}
      position={{
        lat: data_noeud.geometry.coordinates[1],
        lng: data_noeud.geometry.coordinates[0],
      }}
    >
      <Popup>
        <div>
          {/*<h1> {"Nom modèle : " + data_noeud.properties.Nom_modele} </h1>*/}
          <h1> {"Noeud : " + data_noeud.properties.NOM} </h1>
        </div>
      </Popup>
    </Marker>
  ))}

  <GeoJSON
    style={section_style}
    data={section.features}
  />

 <GeoJSON
    style={casier_style}
    data={casier.features}
  />
 </MapContainer>

 );
 }


 export default Macarte;
```

Please Help :)

Answer (score 1):

A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66211478/14218394).
**Legend** component

```
function Legend({ map }) {
  console.log(map);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (map) {
      const legend = L.control({ position: "bottomright" });
      legend.onAdd = () => {
        const div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "legend");
        div.innerHTML =
          "<h4>Legend</h4>"
        return div;
      };

      legend.addTo(map);
    }
  }, [map]); //here add map
  return null;
}
```

in a .css file you can establish rules for the legend then import it into your legend component.

```
.legend {
   padding: 6px 8px;
   font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   line-height: 24px;
   color: rgb(0,0,0)
}

.legend h4 {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 16px;
   margin: 2px 12px 8px;
   color: rgb(0,0,0)
}
```

Then you can simply put the Legend component wherever you want.